# Why is not Corona addEventListener listening my button touch?

Tags: coronasdk, addeventlistener

Here is my code and i'm going nuts. I just did as in Corona Labs examples but it seems like not working. Could you look at it please?

```
 local try= display.newImage("1.png")

 local function hop(event)
   if(event.phase==began) then
            print "hello"
    end
        return true
 end

 try:addEventListener("touch", hop)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close, one minor error - you need quotes around "began".

```
if event.phase == "began" then
```

That will do it.

Comment: My stupidity and cpm is not helpful, either. Thank you, Peach!